# React Native Keyboard dismisses when modal is visible

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, keyboard

I have a chat app where the user is able to mark a message and see more actions. The problem is when I open the full screen modal the keyboard dismisses. I want the keyboard to stay open in the background of the modal.

This is how the modal looks like

[image]

This is what it looks like:

[image]

But this is how it should look like:

[image]